# Change tooltip position where mouse found

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I am using highcharts pie chart and needs to change the tooltip position
to where the mouse is on while it's over the chart.
Currently I tried to change it's position but it's not working.

Here is how i tried to create and use the chart:

```
chartObj = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: container,
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        animation: false,
        backgroundColor: '#e4e6e1',
        height: 300
    },
    colors: colors,
    title: {
        text: title
    },
    tooltip: {
         positioner: function (boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
            return { x: point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft, y: point.plotY + this.chart.plotTop };
        },
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
        percentageDecimals: 1,
        style: {
            color: '#333333',
            fontSize: '12px',
            padding: '8px',
            opacity: 1
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: false,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: width < 1500 ? false : true,
                color:'#000000',
                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () { return this.percentage.toFixed(2) + "%"; },
                connectorWidth: 0,
                distance: 5
            },
            showInLegend: true,
            color: '#000000',
            connectorColor: '#000000',
            point: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    },
    series: [{ type: 'pie',
               name: title,
               visible: chart_visible,
               data: data,
    }],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        floating: false,
        shadow: true
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    }
});
chartObj.series[0].setData(data);

return chartObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `point.x` and `point.y` are always the same for pie slice - they are not mouse position.

Possible workaroud is to use `points.event.mouseOver` and `mouseOut` and create your own tooltip (display some absolute  with values from that event).